# Rails:In-place editing in edit form with submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I want to create my edit form such that it will display the current user information simply as text not in text filed and when user click on the text it will turn into text field and user can edit his information . Changes will be reflect in data base only when user click on submit button.
Simply it is not completely in place editing and not completely like default edit form it is mixture of the behaviour of  both the features.

My form looks like following .it is not complete form these are some of the fields of form.

```
<%=  form_for @contact, :html => { :multipart => true, :class => "contact_form"} do |f| %>

  <% if @contact.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@contact.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this contact from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @contact.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

     <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :f_name, "First Name" %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :f_name %>
     </div>
       <div class ="field">
         <%= f.label :experience, "Total years of experience "%><br/>
         <%= f.select :experience, (0...30),{},{:class => 'select'} %>
       </div>


       <div class="field">
         <%= f.label :l_name, "Last Name" %><br/>
         <%= f.text_field :l_name %>
       </div>


       <div class = "field">
         <%= f.label :primary_practice_area, "Primary practice area"  %><br/>
         <%=  f.select :primary_practice_area , MetaPracticeArea.all.collect {|p| [ p.practice_area, p.id ] }    %>

       </div>

       <div class = "field">
         <%= f.label :phone, "Phone"  %><br/>
         <%= f.text_field :phone %>
       </div>
       <div class="actions">
         <%= f.submit :class => "submit_btn" %>
       </div>
<% end %>
```

and controller and model is default.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the REST_in_place gem: https://github.com/janv/rest_in_place

Comment: I  have tried this ..but i don't want to submit the form while editing i want to submit it through a submit button.

Comment: Then you should use jquery javascript that binds onclick event of a text and makes text invisible;  edit box - visible. smth like that

Answer (score 0):

Check below link for in_place_editing :

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing?view=asciicast

Comment: This i have already checked but i don't want to so this ..i want to submit the form through a button .